# facebook page recommendations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

please, can someone give me quick tutorial in steps, how to get facebook page reccomendations data using facebook graph api? I searched whole internet and it is not working. When I'm making request im recieving `{ "error": { "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (ratings) on node type (Application)", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100, "fbtrace_id": "APyyWaPkSs4XwAsOdwN4oTV" } }`

Json data with reccomendations from facebook page

Comment: `on node type (Application)` - looks like you got the wrong ID there to begin with; you are trying to query this field from an application there, not a page.